# Comparison of running times - similar code runs 4 times slower

Tags: c++, performance, backtracking

I am solving the palindrome partition problem which requires to return all palindrome partitions of a given string (http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/). I found two solutions to this problem. I am having difficulty to understand why there is a huge difference in the running times of these two approaches:

(Assume `bool isPal()` is a given function which tells whether given string is palindrome or not in O(length) time)

1st Solution: (Uses backtracking):

```
void find(string s, int start, vector<string> &r, vector<vector<string> > &res){
    if (start >= s.size()){
        res.push_back(r);
    }else{
    for (int i=start;i<s.size();i++){            
        if (isPal(s.substr(start, i-start+1))){
            r.push_back(s.substr(start,i-start+1));
            find(s,i+1,r,res);        
            r.pop_back();
        }  
    }
    }  
}

vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
    vector<vector<string> > res;
    vector<string> r;
    find(s,0,r,res);
    return res;    
}
```

2nd Solution:

```
vector<vector<string> > partition(string s) {
    vector<vector<string> > answer;

    if(s.size() == 0)
        return answer;

    // if s is Palindrome, push to answer
    if(isPal(s))
        answer.push_back(vector<string>(1,s));

    if(s.size() == 1)
        return answer;

    for(int i=1; i<s.size(); ++i) {
        string s1 = s.substr(0, i);
        string s2 = s.substr(i, s.size()-i);

        if(isPal(s1)) {
            // get sub_answers of partition(s[i:])
            vector<vector<string> > sub_answer = partition(s2);

            // add s1 to the begin of sub_answers
            for(int j=0; j<sub_answer.size(); ++j) {
                sub_answer[j].insert(sub_answer[j].begin(), s1);
                answer.push_back(sub_answer[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Even though both the solutions have the same underlying idea, the 1st solution runs in **108ms**, while the 2nd one takes **472ms** time. Is this because of theoretical inefficiency (maybe 2nd solution solves a single problem multiple times) or because of inefficient implementation (some C++ concepts)? 
Please point out the reason for inefficiency of 2nd solution.

**Note**: Both solutions are correct and give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume both implementations returns the same result?
Other than that, there are to lines worth commenting:

```
sub_answer[j].insert(sub_answer[j].begin(), s1);
```

This forces all the content of `sub_answer[j]` to be shifted back to give space to `s1`. Better add `s1` to the vector before adding the rest.

```
answer.push_back(sub_answer[j]);
```

`sub_answer[j]` is now copied again. Since you don't need `sub_answer[j]` any more, you may use `std::move` to swap ownership in stead of copying:

```
answer.push_back(std::move(sub_answer[j]));
```